# How to get the call stack of a function in eclipse android during debugging?

Tags: android, eclipse

How can i get the call stack of a function during debugging in eclipse.The debug view already shows a call stack but this is not detailed enough.I want to know from where the call came to the function i am looking at right now.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: How could it be more detailed? You click on every method in the call stack, and Eclipse shows you the executed line .

Comment: Then I am missing something.I want to know which method called the method I am looking into(the callbacks in the code).

Answer (score 3):

Just look at the debug view:

[image]

In the above example, the debugger is stopped at the line 45 of the `FileSplit.writeBlock()` method.

This method is called by the `FileSplit.splitFile()` method (which is paused at line 24).

And this `splitFile()` method is called by `FileSplit.main()` (which is paused at line 10).

Clicking on any of these nodes allows seeing the code of the calling method, and allows inspecting the values of all the variables involved in this method.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation along with the image.